# Java's Math.pow() yielding bizarre results in simple case

Tags: java, math, pow

I'm trying to do a simple programming challenge, and I'm running into a bizarre and unrelated issue with the Math.pow() function.

I'm getting that 6 to the power of 1 is 54?

I'm reading a file entered on the command line (via args[0]). That file contains only three numbers:

```
6
75
153
```

And the program I'm running is as follows:

```
public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException{

    File filename = new File(args[0]);
    Scanner file = new Scanner(filename);

    while(file.hasNextLine()){
        String numbers = file.nextLine();
        int numValue = Integer.parseInt(numbers);

        int sumOfPowers = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length(); i++){
            sumOfPowers += Math.pow(numbers.charAt(i), numbers.length());
            System.out.println(Math.pow(numbers.charAt(i), numbers.length()));
            System.out.println(Math.pow(6, 1));
        }

    }
    file.close();
}
```

The output this is generating is odd. Is it against Java rules to create a power function based on these types of values?

Output I get:

```
54.0
6.0
3025.0
6.0
2809.0
6.0
117649.0
6.0
148877.0
6.0
132651.0
6.0
```

Comment: the second line is 6^1 and it outputs 6 just fine

Comment: Yes, so the question is why is it giving me 54 on the line above when the values inside are also 6 and 1

Comment: it will also help better if u upload the contents of ur file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the main misconception here is that `'6'` != `6`  If they were the same you won't need to have different literals.  Instead the ASCII for `'6'` is `(int) '6'` or `54`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is beacause the ascii value of character `6` is 54. Now check your code:

```
Math.pow(numbers.charAt(i)
```

Comment: @leigero np, just accept the answer if you find it useful. The practice of accepting the answers help others facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here `numbers.charAt(i)` returns a `char '6'` and NOT `int 6`.

value of `char '6'` in ASCII is integer value 54.
'0' is 48, '1' is 49, and so on.

Just reset the counting from number 0.

```
Math.pow(numbers.charAt(i) - '0', numbers.length());
```